# I want to make a Career suggestion model

Tags: nlp, recommender-system, tfidf, gensim, cosine-distance

There is a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ravindrasinghrana/job-description-dataset/data) having job titles and the descriptions. when a person enter his skills i need to output which category of job he should do. i have already created that using cosine similarity.(If you can tell me a better approach, that would be helpful too) now i need to give suggestions that he can improve his skills.

if he entered his skills as Statistics and python. model should be able to say to learn data science. Or learn data analytics.

Can you give me a suggestion on how to do that? An approach is much appreciated.

(Develop a LLM is not an option)

I am stucked here. any help is much appreciated